# Is it possible for a Flutter for Android activity to NOT be fullscreen? Or have no UI at all?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm building a somewhat basic app (only testing on Android for now) with multiple lists, one of which is an Inbox list. I can share text from other apps to my app, and it works well.

However, I would like the app to handle the intent without launching the full app UI. For example, if I share a URL from the browser to my app, I would like it to be handled in the background, save the URL to Firestore, and show a toast to the user indicating that it was successful.

Ideally, I would like to put two entries in the share menu, one to add to the Inbox and show a toast as described above, and a second entry that gives the user a modal dialog that floats above the sharing-from app, which allows the user to choose a different list to save to.

I think I'll have to make a (for example) ShareActivity.java, and add it to AndroidManifest.xml, but I have no idea where to go after that, or even if that's the right approach.

Comment: If you do not want a UI then don't use Activities. Android supports showing either 0 or 1 activities.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response, or maybe I should rephrase the question. My app has a UI, but when I send a text intent to the app I do not want to show the UI. I just want a background worker of some sort to save the intent text as a firestore document, and display a toast so that the user knows something happened. 

If I can't accomplish this by creating a separate activity aside from the MainActivity, then how should it be done? I can't figure out how to run Dart/Flutter code without launching the UI.

Comment: To my knowledge Flutter is tied to Dart and vice versa. The beginning section of this [open issue post in Flutter's github proposing an architecture](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37910) may help explain the current state of the tools.